# VBA find decimals and copy

Tags: excel

I am trying to find value that contain decimal point in the column F, then copy those row into another sheet.

I don't know how to find the value of decimal. If I set the `Value = "1"`, it will work, it will copy the row that have number 1 in it to another sheet. Need some help

```
Sub SpecialCopy()

Dim targetSh As Worksheet
Set targetSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Error")
Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(i, 6).Value = "." Then
            Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 6)).Copy 
            Destination:=targetSh.Range("A" & targetSh.Cells _
                              (Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Usually i got to do it manually, i will CTRL + F that collumn F, search . then it will show me cell that contain . example 0.3 0.5 1.5

Comment: If you want to use you own code, try to find decimal values by `Instr(1,Cells(i, 6).Value,".",vbBinaryCompare)<>0` Instead of `Cells(i, 6).Value = "."`

Comment: Thanks!! David Garcia Bodego. One last question. How do i round them up to nearest 1? for that Rows F. Usually excel i got to =Roundup (F2, 0). This is just for 1 cell, but i want to round up the whole collumn . Thanks!!

Comment: If you are interested to use the same function just use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Roundup(F2,0)` as you will use in Excel. If you need to one column, just add a loop.

Comment: You can do it using excel formulas easily. You need to use a helper column.